# How do I call a JsonResult from javascript?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I would like to call my JsonResult after a pageload, not on a submit button.  I have two BeginForm functions.

```
$("#loadTableForm").ready(function() {
    //$.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(response) {
});

<%using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
   //data
   <%using (Html.BeginForm("LoadTable", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "loadTableForm" })) {%>
      //Table here should be loaded after page is loaded
   <% } %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: I'm not an expert on jQuery but I don't think you're supposed to use the ready function on a regular element, just the document. You use it when you want something to occur when the DOM is loaded.

    $(document).ready(function() {
       $.post("/home/foobar", ...);
    });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create your controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetData()
{
    IList<Person> people = GetPeople();

    return Json(people);
}
```

Next you make an ajax call to get the json data:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "<%= Url.Action("GetData") %>",
            data: "{}", // pass in data usually
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                // TODO work with this data
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I am not sure what I did wrong.  I have the JsonResult function in the controller.  The problem is passing from the javascript to the controller

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a form within another form, that isn't valid HTML.  So you'll need to just have a single form and then use the page load function to make the ajax call like so:

```
$(function() {
    // anything in here happens after the page loads
});
```